# Pine-script optimization

Tags: optimization, parameters, pine-script

In AmiBroker there is optimize option. It allows you to fine tune values for indicators or even any other parameters. Is there anything like that in pine script? couldn't find it easily using google.

Comment: Do you mean changing the indicator's input parameters?

Comment: Yes, changing indicator parameters. PineScript should check permutation combinations of the parameters. e.g. Let's look at simple example, I want to trigger buy/sell when 5ema crosses 13ema and book the profit in 15 points and loss in 5 points.  Now I want to find out whether this 15 point is right or should it be 11 or 12, or 13 or 14...also what should be the better SL points.

Comment: No automatic optimization option available in pine script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Can't be done automatically yet on TV. Adding the feature is being considered though.

Comment: This is one place where you can vote on the concept, but TV is aware that it's a highly-requested feature, as are hundreds of others, so it's a matter of getting to it. While there is no ETA yet, it's a safe bet to assume it will happen at some point: https://getsatisfaction.com/tradingview/topics/platform-for-building-back-testing-optimizing-and-deploying-automated-trading-systems

Comment: Any updates on this feature. The request link is down. Other solutions??

Comment: It still can't be done on TradingView. It's been discussed but it's not in the dev pipeline yet, so no ETA.

Comment: Any update on this? can u pl provide ETA?

Comment: There is no ETA yet.

Answer (score 0):

there are private chrome extensions. just a couple months ago there were some public versions but TV has started banning people and finding ways to shut down the extensions ability to properly see and feel the page

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no optimization in Pine Script and no plans to add it. Here is the reply I got from support about this (on 23 February 2023):

> "We currently have no plans to integrate machine learning or strategy
> optimization features, but we do plan to add a feature that will allow
> you to read external data sources from Pine, including .csv files"

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33923144)